# ASP.NET MVC Helper to add items to arbitrary list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm displaying an editable list of items using this [technique](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Directorships)
```

This works successfully for listing and editing the existing list items, but I want to add new items as well. In the past I've written some client-side script (jQuery) to add additional items to the list and correctly name the field indexes. However the scripts were hard-coded to the model property names.

I would like to be able to reuse that scripts for all lists. Something like:

```
@Html.EditorAndAdderFor(m => m.Directorships)
```

Does anyone know of existing solutions to this or possible implementations?

Comment: Use a partial view with a form to add a new one within the editor page for directorships

Comment: @user3153169 I don't quite follow. Can you elaborate in a post?

Comment: How exactly would expect this to work?  Server side helpers don't add client side javascript, so there's no way to make your server side helper make anything like that work on the client.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: I would expect it to work in exactly the same way an `HtmlHelper.EditorFor()` helper would work - by adding the correct client side markup and script in a generic way that would work on any list of arbitrary objects. Probably in the same way that the `EditorFor()` method can support Unobtrusive Client-side Validation.

Comment: EditorFor doesn't add any script.  It only adds data attributes, which script that already exists can use.  You have to write script regardless.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Yes I understand, but as mentioned, I have in the past written scripts to do this with jQuery and I would like to reuse those scripts instead of hard-coding them. So it is certainly possible to do it. My question is if there isn't already an existing (possibly open source) solution to this instead of me doing it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you want to have ONE page with the functionality of displaying the data, altering it and adding new.

Display and edit can ben accomplished by the @Html.EditorFor as you already did. To have add functionality in the same page, you should create a partial view with the form, something like this:

Your page:

```
@model MyProject.MyModels.MyModel

// The @Html.EditorFor stuff..

@Html.Partial("_AddForm")
```

_AddForm.cshtml:

```
@model MyProject.MyModels.Directorship

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDirectorshipActionName")) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Attribute1)
    // etc..

    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
}
```

You could add Ajax functionality to stay on the page and reload or load the new data when added a new directorship